# Does ViewState require Server resources? I thought not

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I read this somewhere:

*"Because the view state for a given page 
must be kept ON THE SERVER, it is possible for the current 
state to be out of synchronization with the current page of 
the browser, if the user uses the Back feature on the 
browser to go back in the history*"

I suspect that this may not be the default setting but instead an option to store the viewstate on the server, as what would the point of storing the ViewState in the page AND the server be? Am I correct?

If ViewState is stored on the server, how does one avoid the BackButton isue described here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET ViewState is stored in the client in one (or more) hidden HTML input field. I'd be really interested in seeing where you read that incorrect statement.

The server totally forgets ViewState once sent. As a security measure against tampering, ASP.NET can encrypt it and validate it against its key. If you use a set key (rather than auto-generating one), that view state will be valid even if the server has been shut down and rebooted entirely. All which illustrates that nothing in view state is stored on the server.

Comment: I think the clue here might be the use of "view state" in the quote rather than "ViewState" and probably applies to a different approach to maintaining state that doesn't involve the use of the ASP.NET ViewState mechanism.

Comment: @Lazarus - Excellent point; I hadn't noticed that particular tidbit, but that's just the sort of possibility I would expect to explain such a statement.

Comment: @Andrew Barber :  Just the kind of tidbit that a pedant, such as I, would notice ;)

Comment: I read it in a posting. http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/4745.html, but I recall seeing this point in more than one place. Also, I vaguely recall experiencing an error myself where the ViewState was eiether corrupt or out of sync with the server...

Comment: @Chad - It can become corrupt, yes. But not 'out of sync', because it's not synced with anything. I'll look over that link.

Comment: @Chad - both  of those answers on that page are not very helpful due to some incorrect information. I find it funny that the person you quote said "No server resources required" as an advantage, but then said what you quoted, below. He seems to be confused. He also mentioned mobile controls (which is separate, really), but doesn't seem to be talking about mobile controls otherwise.

Comment: @Chad - as for the first answer, it says as a disadvantage that "good hacker can get the data easily". This is simply untrue when the ViewState is encrypted.